# Time series ordering

Tags: arrays

I have a 200 data files to process. I need a solution for one of the files and I would do same for the rest of the files. It is a typical daily time series problem.

My rainfall data is arranged thus: 1990 to 2011 as years, under each year are 12 months, and in front of each month are 29 or 30 or 31 days depending on the month.

My problem is to take all the days in each month and place them beneath that month and for each year. The result will be two column vectors; one for dates and one for rainfall on each day, in each month in each year.

Thanks in advance.

Asong.

my data is shaped as:

```
1960           1           2           3           4           5           6       4
1961           1           2           3           4           5           6       4
```

and I want it to be 1960
                     1
                     .
                     .
                     N
                     1961
                      1
                      .
                      .
                      N
etc. as a column not row form.

Comment: i am not sure what you are getting at?  Because the example data doesn't fit into what you are wanting.  More detail is necessary

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer using reshape(a.',1,[]).

However, one problem remains. My data contains 31 days in all months. How can I tell matlab to delete last two or three days in February and one day in April and other months which are supposed to have 30 days but have 31 in my time series?